# Infranview MultiTiff Conversion

Tags: tiff

I'm trying to convert a number of single tiffs to a multi-page tiff in Infranview by using the command line feature:

```
i_view32.exe /multitif=(c:\test.tif,c:\test1.tif,c:\test2.tif...c:\test270.tif)\killmesoftly
```

The actual command line is 17,000 characters.

but all of the images I create stop at page 71 when they should go one.  Has anyone tried to do this before?  It might be an issue with the length of the command line limit, but I would that would cause an invalid command and an InfranView error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article may of help:

[What is the command line length limit?](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx)

Are there other ways to send data to IrfanView, for example piping it to stdin like one would on Unix?

Comment: This was an issue with the length of the dos command line.  I don't see any way to get around that so the question is moot.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Wow, yeah I just reached this limit on my own application at 2159 characters... just over the 2048 char limit.